# python Unicode string splitting/ to json conversion

Tags: python, json, unicode

I have a bunch of Unicode strings and I am looking for a quickest way to extract values from the string.

```
In [161]: data1 = u'NAME: abc\nSchool Name: CD\n________________\nENG: B   \nMat: B   '
In [162]: print data1
NAME: abc
School Name: CD
________________
ENG: B   
Mat: B
```

Alternatively, is there a way to process it using json in python.

Comment: What sort of container holds the "bunch" of strings? A list? A text file? Something else?

Comment: The number of string at a time is one like the example, but I have around 50 fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the following solution working now.

```
data1 = u'NAME: abc\nSchool Name: CD\n________________\nENG: B   \nMat: B   '

import re
from itertools import izip
data2 = re.split(r'[:\n________________]+',data1)
i = iter(data2)
ans = dict(izip(i, i))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the data for NAME:, School Name:, etc.

I would use a dictionary and split the data to insert it.  So the code would look something like this

```
data=data1.split("\n")
info={}

for d in data:
    info[d.split(":")[0]]=d.split(":")[1]
```

Then you can reference info for the data like so:

```
info["NAME"], info["School Name"]
```

etc

EDIT: no for loop

You could, based on which field you are looking for, do this:

```
info=data1.split(field)[1].split("\n")[0]
```

Comment: The data that I have is long. Basically, I want to avoid the for loop in pyhton -if possible.

Comment: check my edit i think that will work where field is the field you are looking for

Comment: Still I am required to loop through the fields. I am unable to test the first answer, have you considered the third row in the data1?

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to @QuinnFTW, I would create a dict, but I prefer dict comprehensions to for loops. Once you have the data in a dict, you can convert to JSON easily with `json.dumps`:

```
data1 = u'NAME: abc\nSchool Name: CD\n________________\nENG: B   \nMat: B   '

data1 = dict((item.strip()
              for item in line.split(':',1))
             for line in data1.splitlines()
             if ':' in line)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(data1)

import json
print json.dumps(data1)
```

Result:

```
{u'ENG': u'B', u'Mat': u'B', u'NAME': u'abc', u'School Name': u'CD'}
{"Mat": "B", "NAME": "abc", "School Name": "CD", "ENG": "B"}
```